# Stuck on a particular step of finding the integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{n}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

Here, $n\in \mathbb Z$ is square-free, $R$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{n}]$, and $\alpha = a+b\sqrt{n}$.

---

> [image]

---

I have shown that $a \in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb Z$ statement.

I have shown the if and only if statement.

I have shown that if $a=\frac{1}{2}$ then $b \in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb Z$ statement.

**But I am stuck on the last sentence.** **What do we need to do for this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just asserting that $1/2$ is not in $R$, which is clear because it is not the solution of a monic polynomial equation with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$, i.e. it is not integral over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I know $1/2$ is not integral, but what is the last sentence asking to show?

Comment: @AlJebr That's what my answer addresses. It's saying that if $a=1/2$, then $b$ cannot be $0$, because $1/2\notin R$.

Comment: What about the $(1/2)b =0$ impossible part?

Comment: @AlJebr I think you're misreading it. It is not saying $(1/2)b=0$. It is "we may assume $b=0$ or $1/2$. **Period. And** $b=0$ is impossible."

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I did misread it. I thought the "." after $1/2$ was an error and I thought he meant to write $(1/2)\cdot b =0$.

Comment: @AlJebr Sure, no problem.

Comment: So, we show $b=0$ is impossible. Now why are we assuming $b=1/2$?

Comment: @AlJebr That's the other option. It can be achieved by adding or subtracting a multiple of $\sqrt n$.